# Google maps for SalesForce

Tags: visualforce, geolocation, google-map

I am trying to use Google Maps for my Organizations SalesForce account. We have around 100 users and they might access map frequently. Should I get any licence to use Google Map API ?

I found this [Terms of Use](http://pages.arrowpointe.com/2014-01-30FindNearbyAlternative_GoogleMapsAPIAlertfromSalesforce.html) which says

- **You use the Google API to get a Google map view inside of your salesforce.com instance**
- **You have inserted a public key (as opposed to a Google Maps API for  Business licensed key) into a VisualForce page to render a maps view**
- **You have installed any AppExchange solution that makes calls to Google  (i.e. “Find Nearby”) that do not have a commercial agreement with Google**

**If you use Google Maps or Google Maps API in any of three categories outlined above, we recommend that you visit this page: https://developers.google.com/maps/support/availability to get a Google Maps for Business license.**

Comment: Can you talk more about how your organization wants to use Google Maps? Do you just need a map embedded somewhere within an object or do you need something more elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how much this relates to Salesforce specifically. If you need to use Google Maps in your VF pages, you can try [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/). [Here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000guBkAAI) is a guidance to integrate it with your VF page(Please modify any version related mismatches by going through documentations). 
About the license and pricing check [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage). It's upto you to decide based on the number of API requests that will be sent.

> If you think your website or application will generate high map loads consistently in the long-term, you should consider one of the following options:
>
> - Modify your application so that your usage is less than 25 000 map loads per day.
> - Enroll for automated billing of excess map loads in the Google APIs Console.
> - Purchase a Maps API for Business license.

For web applications, JavaScript API is the simplest way to integrate Google Maps in my experience.